# How to make an activity invisble once it started a fragment and return once it's done?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to create a fragment that once the activity started it, its screen won't be seen until the fragment is done, even if the fragment's layout is not covering the whole screen.
Is there a way to do it?
I tried many examples across the net like FragmentTransaction.add / FragmentTransaction.replace but they don't seem to get it done.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to give to fragment layout "GONE" visibility and then switching to "VISIBLE" once onResume() method in the fragment gets called?

Comment: I've, but it doesn't hide the Activity behind it.